# How to solve the recurrence of T(n) = 2 * T(n/3) + 3/2 * T(n/4) + 5 * T(n/2) + Theta(n^2), p = 2,574359

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

How to solve the recurrence of T(n) = 2 * T(n/3) + 3/2 * T(n/4) + 5 * T(n/2) + Theta(n^2), p = 2,574359
I don't understand how to solve so complex reccurrence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find an upper-bound like the following:

```
T(n) <= (2 + 3/2 + 5) * T(n/2) + Theta(n^2) = 8.5 T(n/2) + Theta(n^2)
```

And using master theorem, you can say `T(n) = O(n^{log(8.5)) ~ O(n^{3.09})`.

Also, you can use [akra-bazzi theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method) to find a tighter bound. First, we need to solve the following equation

```
2 * (1/3)^p + 3/2 (1/4)^p + 5 * (1/2)^p = 1
```

After solving, we know that `p ~ 2.57`. Hence, by the theorem we find that:

```
T(n) = Theta(n^{2.57} (1 + int(x^2/x^{3.57} dx, 1, n) ) ) = 
       Theta(n^{2.57} (1 + int(1/x^{1.57} dx, 1, n) ) )
```

As `int(1/x^{1.57} dx, 1, n) < 3`, we can say `T(n) = Theta(n^{2.57})`.